# Show/Hide content based on drop-down selection

Tags: javascript, php

This is my first time posting and I just started learning how to code js.
So basically, what I want to know is how do I show or hide content based on the item the user picks from a drop down list.

Here's the php code:

```
<script src="js/category.js"></script>

<?php
include 'dbh.php';

$sqli='SELECT * FROM categories';
$getdata=mysqli_query($conn,$sqli);

echo "
<form action='category_input.php' method='POST' id='categoryform'>

Category: <select name='category_id'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata))
        {
        echo 
        '<option value='.$row['id'].'>'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
        };
echo '</select></form>';


echo "
<div style='display:none;' id='computer'>

<br><br>
Part Number:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='part_number' placeholder='Serial Number'>

<br><br>
Serial Number:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='serial_number' placeholder='Serial Number'>

<br><br>
<label>Description</label>
<textarea rows='4' cols='50' name='description' form='categoryform'>
</textarea>
<br><br>

</div>
";

echo "
<div style='display:none;' id='peripheral'>

<br><br>
Brand:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='brand' placeholder='Brand'>

<br><br>
Type:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='type' placeholder='Type'>

<br><br>
Type:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='type' placeholder='Type'>

<br><br>
Part Number:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='part_number' placeholder='Part Number'>

<br><br>
Serial Number:
<input type='text' style='width:200px' name='serial_number' placeholder='Serial Number'>
<br><br>

</div>";
```

Here's the category.js code:

```
var selectedVal =  document.getElementsByName("category_id").value;

if(selectedVal == '1')  // Put any condition here selectedVal == '1'
{
    var element = document.getElementById('computer');
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden';      // Hide
}
else
{
    var element = document.getElementById('computer');
    element.style.visibility = 'visible';     // Show
}
```

Here's the category_name list:

```
PC
Notebook
Server
Scanner
Printer
DVD
AccessPoint/Wireless
Mikrotik
Fingerprint
Monitor
Rack Server
DVR
FotoCopy
TV
Modem
Camera
External Storage
ThinClient
Projector
STB BOX(Indihome TV)
VOIP
UPS
Switch
Keyboard
Mouse
```

I tried to check if it works when I click on category_id = 1 but it doesn't echo the div id="computer"

Sorry for the long post and please tell me if I need to add more information and feedback on how I should do future posts.

Edit: added js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Dropdown Show/Hide Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195963/javascript-dropdown-show-hide-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**
So I found a working solution:

```
<script>
function populateField() {
    selectedVal = document.getElementById('select').value;
    if((selectedVal == '1') || (selectedVal == '2') || (selectedVal == '3'))
    {   
        $("#computer").show();
        $("#peripheral").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#computer").hide();
        $("#peripheral").show();
    }
}
```

And using this:
`<select style='width:100%;' name='category_name' id='select' onchange='populateField()'>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var selectedVal =  document.getElementsByName("category_id").value;

if(selectedVal == '1')  // Put any condition here selectedVal == '1'
{
    var element = document.getElementById('id');
    element.style.visibility = 'hidden';      // Hide
}
else
{
    var element = document.getElementById('id');
    element.style.visibility = 'visible';     // Show
}
```

Comment: *"what I want to know is how do I show or hide content"*

Comment: How do I hide/show the different div's?
For example, I want it to show div id="computer"

Comment: Yes you can, just select the specific html element and apply show hide on it

Comment: hmm, ok thanks - sorry I'm very new to javascript as I literally started learning about it like an hour ago xD